# How do you merge 2 outlook archives together?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, pst

I have 2 outlook archives (.pst files) that I wish to merge together.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to open one in Outlook. Then select File > Import, and import the second pst into the first, checking the "include subfolders" button.

If these are not the 2003/2007 version of PST, but are from Outlook 2000 or earlier, they have a 2 GB limit and other issues, so I would recommend creating a new PST, and importing both archives into the new one.

Comment: I agree with the answer above, but suggest adding the point to check 'do not import duplicates' underneath where you supply the path to the file. That will give you a true merge. (can't edit questions or comments yet, thus the format of a new answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:- Create a New Blank PST file;

1.) First of all open MS Outlook Program.

2.) Click on the “New Items” and select “More Items” from the drop down menu. After that select “Outlook Data File” option.

3.) After that select the location to save PST file and provide a name for the new PST file. Now click on “Ok” button.

Step 2:- Import all PST files into new blank PST file

1.) Now click on “File” tab > “Open” > “Import”.

2.) After that an “Import and Export Wizard” will appear. Select “Import from another program or file” from the list and click on “Next”.

3.) Now select file type to import from. Click on “Outlook Data File (.pst)” and click on “Next”.

4.) Click on “Browse” and select the file to import. Check the box “Do not import duplicates” and then click on “Next”.

5.) Select the folder to import from. Check the box “Include subfolders” and “Import items into the same folder in”. Then click on “Finish”.

Some times these manual method doesn't work. In that situation, you can go with third party tool. I found **GainTools merge pst tool**. Free trial available.